# php restrict direct url access

Tags: php, html

I have a few files like:
`_main.php_`, `_header.html_`, `_page1.php_`, `_page2.php_`,..

The *header.html* is included in *main.php* has a link to *page1.php* and *page2.php*. I want to restrict access to *page1.php* and *page2.php* to be accessed only when user uses the link provided through the link on *main.php*.

I came across a solution to DEFINE a session variable and use, but in this case, it seems to work only with included files, and not the PHP pages called via links from the main page.

Comment: You can use `.htaccess` to do that.

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam how? I only know of the possibility to restrict access to those pages completely, which won't allow it to be accessed only via link.

Comment: @user3894937 This seems to be an odd request. How do you plan to account for bookmarking pages? Refreshing pages?

Comment: Without using `.htaccess`, you could add a `GET` variable in the hyperlink then check for that variable on `page1.php`/`page2.php`?

Comment: This is simply not how the web works. Why exactly do you want this? You should clarify, because it  doesn't make a lot of sense as is.

Comment: this is becuase if anyone wants to use the functional of page1, he should be going only through main.php where their login details are recorded, else users are able to simply run a script on command line to get the work done without finding any need to use the main tool

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam,@Ben Pearl Kahan: Thanks for your suggestion, i tried with .htacess, it helps in removing access to that folder where .htaccess file is placed. But when i give the php file name too, the page is getting displayed :(

Answer (score 2):

Create a file in your folder as `.htaccess` and copy paste this below to that file :

```
Deny from all
```

And in the same folder you wanna restrict it, create a file named `index.html`, and copy paste this to the file :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this help you out :)

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this. with this solution, the directory url gives forbidden message. But when i enter the specific file name in that path, ..../page2.php, the file still opens

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply define a constant in your main.php file like

```
 define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
```

check this in your page1.php and page2.php like

```
defined('CONSTANT') or die( "No direct access" );
```

Comment: This is good, but I would look to define the constant in a config file so it can be used more widely across the site.

Comment: @TheSk8rJesus sure it would be a great idea.

Comment: i have tried using define, it is not working. probably becuase it works with a file included using @inclue and as page1.php is not an included file and is called when a user clicks on a hyperlink from the main.php